# Avoid ImmutableJS Map converting arrays to List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Curently if I have `m.set(someArray)` where m is a `Map`, it will try to convert `someArray` to Immutable `List`. How do I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a copy of the array, instead:

```
m.set(someArray.slice());
```

Note that, if the array contains reference values (objects, arrays), the references are copied. `.slice()` is only a shallow copy.